# How to interrupt the awaiting in a `for-await` loop / Swift

Tags: swift, async-await, storekit, storekit2

I'm wondering how to stop a `for-await` loop from "awaiting".

Here's the loop. I use it to listen to new `Transaction`s with `storekit2`:

```
    transactionListener = Task(priority: .background) { [self] in
        // wait for transactions and process them as they arrive
        for await verificationResult in Transaction.updates {
            if Task.isCancelled { print("canceled"); break }

            // --- do some funny stuff with the transaction here ---
            await transaction.finish()
        }
        print("done")
    }
```

As you can see, `Transaction.updates` is awaited and returns a new transaction whenever one is created. When the App finishes, I cancel the loop with `transactionListener.cancel()` - but the cancel is ignored as the `Transaction.updates` is waiting for the next transaction to deliver and there's no direct way in the API to stop it (like, e.g. `Task.sleep()` does)

The issues starts, when I run unit-tests. The listener from a previous test is still listening while the next test is already running. This produces very unreliable test results and crashes our CI/CD pipeline. I nailed it down to the shown piece of code and the described issue.

So, **question**: Is it possible to interrupt a `for-await` loop from awaiting? I have something like the Unix/Linux command `kill -1` in mind. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do that actually. Probably avoid calling that in unit tests?

Comment: "The issues starts, when I run unit-tests. The listener from a previous test is still listening while the next test is already running. This produces very unreliable test results." Sounds like the unit test is written wrong. Do not test the network or Apple's code.

Comment: @matt, that's right. The intention of the test ist to verify the code that is in `--- do some funny stuff with the transaction here ---`. Therefore I'd like to stop and start the listener as I like - Apple's implementation of this `AsyncSequence` should to its job.
On the other hand, @Sulthan, the listener-loop is necessary in production code. If it is omitted, I'd miss important information about the inApp purchases, especially renewals of subscriptions.

Comment: But since the issue is really about the test, as you yourself say, and since you don't show us the test code, this is pointless hand-waving.

Comment: jboi, we need a [stand-alone, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You’re not even showing us where `transaction` is defined/set. But we need to be able to manifest the problem. That having been said, simply checking for cancellation in the `for` loop is generally not sufficient. You typically want to make the task that you are awaiting cancellable. Once you hit an `await`, this code suspends the loop until the task you are awaiting finishes (or, as I said before, handles cancellations, itself).

Comment: I.e., if suspended at an `await`, it cannot reach your `if Task.isCancelled …` (or `try Task.checkCancellation` is often a better pattern, as it propagates the `CancellationError`). However if the transaction is cancellable, that problem goes away. But we can't say on the basis of what has been shared thus far…